# SQL run command if row exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to make the following pseudocode work:

`` SELECT IF(
          EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE `email`="admin" AND `token`="blablabla"),
          (UPDATE * FROM sometable WHERE `var`="notimportant"),
          "NOT_AUTHORIZED"); ``

What I'm trying to achieve is running code based on the presence of a row, and if it doesn't exists return a message, or something usable. If it does exists, run another SQL command instead, and return those results.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is `update *` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent is a bit hard to follow from the invalid syntax.  But the gist of your question is that you can use a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE sometable
    SET . . . 
    WHERE var = 'notimportant' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = 'admin' AND token = 'blablabla');
```

You can also represent this as a `JOIN`.  Assuming the subquery returns at most one row:

```
UPDATE sometable t CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT 1
        FROM users
        WHERE email = 'admin' AND token = 'blablabla'
        LIMIT 1
       ) x
    SET . . . 
    WHERE var = 'notimportant' ;
```

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for! I didn't realize you could use AND if it was unrelated to the data. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hrhmmhmm.... It looks like MySQL is executing `AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = 'admin' AND token = 'blablabla')` for every row it matches, is there a way to turn this around?